# Restate linguistic example

Tags: linguistics, gb4e

I have made a numbered example with the package GB4E. I want to restate this example with the same number. I.e. istead of just refering to the example with `\ref`, i want the whole thing to show up again. How?

The output of the following is what i would like to restate:

`\begin{exe}
\ex \label{dog} Bonzo is a dog
\end{exe}`

Comment: You should probably add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for people to play with to increase your chances of getting an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `\exr` macro to refer to a previously labeled example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
\ex\label{mylabel}
  \begin{xlist}
    \ex An example.
    \ex Another example.
  \end{xlist}
\end{exe}

Here is a repeated example

\begin{exe}
\exr{mylabel}
  \begin{xlist}
    \ex An example.
    \ex Another example.
  \end{xlist}
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Great to know, thanks! I did however misinform you. My minimal example should be like this:

`\begin{exe} \ex \label{dog} \gll Bonzo is a dog\\word word word word\\\glt A sentence \end{exe}`

Your method doesn't seem to work with this.

Comment: @Man Edit your question showing a *complete* example like mine that doesn't work.  The method I show works independent of the use of `\gll` etc. (Although for single examples, (i.e. those not involving `xlist`, it's best to put the `\label` command after the example text instead of right after `\ex`.)

Comment: You are right. It does work. I must have been sloppy in my previous attempt.